# Android app crashes with StackOverflowError Retrofit 2 + RxJava 1

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, stack-overflow, rx-java2

I'm using Retrofit2 with RxJava1 to make network calls and I'm getting the following crash logs from my users through Crashlytics quite often.
I can't really pinpoint the issue and neither have I been able to reproduce this crash on my end.
Can anyone suggest why it could be happening?

One of my guesses is it might have something to do with me using **RxJava1** + **Retrofit2** but haven't found any concrete evidence for that yet.

Upgrading the whole app to RxJava2 will be a huge effort which I want to keep as a last resort to try.
I'm using the following RxJava and Retrofit dependencies :

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
implementation 'moe.banana:moshi-jsonapi:3.3.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
```

---

Some device observations:

**Operating Systems** : Android 9 and 10 (not sure if happening on previous versions as well)

**Background state** : 53% in background

**Rooted** : No

The code near line 45 of my **Interceptor** class pointed in logs is :

```
@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request.Builder requestBuilder = chain.request().newBuilder();
    requestBuilder = addDefaultHeaders(requestBuilder);
    requestBuilder = addAuthorizationHeader(requestBuilder);
    requestBuilder = addSocketHeader(requestBuilder);
    requestBuilder = addCustomHeaders(requestBuilder);
    return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build());         // Line 45
}
```

Also, the code near line 48 of my **TokenAuthenticator** class pointed in logs is :

```
@Override
public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
if (response.code() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {
   Log.d(TAG, "Code 401 received when making API call");
   retrofit2.Response<JwtToken> refreshResponse =
      mAuthenticationRepository.authRefresh().execute();  // Line 48
```

I'm making REST calls in general in the following way :

```
Observable<ItemRealm> localItem = mItemLocalDataSource.getItem(itemId);
    Observable<ItemRealm> remoteItem = apiService()
            .getItem(itemId)
            .flatMap((Func1<Item, Observable<ItemRealm>>) item -> {
                Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                try {
                    mItemLocalDataSource.saveItem(item, realm);
                    return mItemLocalDataSource.getItem(itemId, realm);
                } finally {
                    realm.close();
                }
            });
    return Observable.merge(localItem, remoteItem);
```

The following are the crash logs :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread.
   at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:62)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:459)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Caused by java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1041KB
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:175)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at com.soapboxhq.goodtalk_android.data.remote.TeamApiInterceptor.intercept(TeamApiInterceptor.java:45)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
       at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
       at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
       at com.soapboxhq.goodtalk_android.data.remote.TokenAuthenticator.authenticate(TokenAuthenticator.java:48)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.followUpRequest(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:288)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:158)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at com.soapboxhq.goodtalk_android.data.remote.TeamApiInterceptor.intercept(TeamApiInterceptor.java:45)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
       at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
       at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
       at com.soapboxhq.goodtalk_android.data.remote.TokenAuthenticator.authenticate(TokenAuthenticator.java:48)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.followUpRequest(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:288)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:158)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at com.soapboxhq.goodtalk_android.data.remote.TeamApiInterceptor.intercept(TeamApiInterceptor.java:45)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
       at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
       at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
       at com.soapboxhq.goodtalk_android.data.remote.TokenAuthenticator.authenticate(TokenAuthenticator.java:48)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.followUpRequest(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:288)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:158)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at com.soapboxhq.goodtalk_android.data.remote.TeamApiInterceptor.intercept(TeamApiInterceptor.java:45)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
       at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
       at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
       at com.soapboxhq.goodtalk_android.data.remote.TokenAuthenticator.authenticate(TokenAuthenticator.java:48)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.followUpRequest(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:288)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:158)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at com.soapboxhq.goodtalk_android.data.remote.TeamApiInterceptor.intercept(TeamApiInterceptor.java:45)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
       at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
       at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
       at com.soapboxhq.goodtalk_android.data.remote.TokenAuthenticator.authenticate(TokenAuthenticator.java:48)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.followUpRequest(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:288)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:158)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at com.soapboxhq.goodtalk_android.data.remote.TeamApiInterceptor.intercept(TeamApiInterceptor.java:45)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
       at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
       at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
       at com.soapboxhq.goodtalk_android.data.remote.TokenAuthenticator.authenticate(TokenAuthenticator.java:48)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.followUpRequest(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:288)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:158)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at com.soapboxhq.goodtalk_android.data.remote.TeamApiInterceptor.intercept(TeamApiInterceptor.java:45)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
       at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
       at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
       at com.soapboxhq.goodtalk_android.data.remote.TokenAuthenticator.authenticate(TokenAuthenticator.java:48)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.followUpRequest(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:288)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:158)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at com.soapboxhq.goodtalk_android.data.remote.TeamApiInterceptor.intercept(TeamApiInterceptor.java:45)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
       at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
       at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
       at com.soapboxhq.goodtalk_android.data.remote.TokenAuthenticator.authenticate(TokenAuthenticator.java:48)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.followUpRequest(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:288)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:158)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at com.soapboxhq.goodtalk_android.data.remote.TeamApiInterceptor.intercept(TeamApiInterceptor.java:45)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
       at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
       at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
       at com.soapboxhq.goodtalk_android.data.remote.TokenAuthenticator.authenticate(TokenAuthenticator.java:48)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.followUpRequest(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:288)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:158)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at com.soapboxhq.goodtalk_android.data.remote.TeamApiInterceptor.intercept(TeamApiInterceptor.java:45)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
       at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
       at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
       at com.soapboxhq.goodtalk_android.data.remote.TokenAuthenticator.authenticate(TokenAuthenticator.java:48)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.followUpRequest(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:288)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:158)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at com.soapboxhq.goodtalk_android.data.remote.TeamApiInterceptor.intercept(TeamApiInterceptor.java:45)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
       at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
       at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$RequestArbiter.request(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:171)
       at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OperatorMap.java:99)
       at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
       at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:152)
       at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:138)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
       at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8666)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:250)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:147)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromArray$FromArrayProducer.fastPath(OnSubscribeFromArray.java:76)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromArray$FromArrayProducer.request(OnSubscribeFromArray.java:58)
       at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromArray.call(OnSubscribeFromArray.java:32)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromArray.call(OnSubscribeFromArray.java:24)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
       at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8666)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
       at rx.internal.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(CachedThreadScheduler.java:220)
       at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:459)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
And please let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: Looks like the code is trying to authenticate recursively inside an okhttp failure. For example, trying to log in, fail, try to log the error remotely for which login is required, which fails so try to log that, etc.

Comment: Paste this line in API call code ".observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())"

Comment: @akarnokd Yes that's what it seems like but I debugged and checked where it could possibly go into a recursive loop, but didn't find it anywhere.

Comment: @Arpitbandil Yes, I'm observing the code on mainThread itself.

Comment: Without the source code to look through, I can't offer you much advice. I'd look into those `com.soapboxhq.goodtalk_android.*` methods listed in the stacktrace for clues.

Comment: @akarnokd Sorry for the delayed response, I was away for a while. As you asked, I added some code around the two places which were pointing to my code in the crash logs. Please have a look if you can see some issue there.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: `mAuthenticationRepository.authRefresh().execute();` keeps failing on the current thread and thus you have a StackOverflow. Maybe this should somehow made an async call so the stack won't grow endlessly. However, repeated auth fails should be stopped completely eventually, which requires app redesign I suppose.

Comment: @akarnokd Yea i tried testing that line of code many times and it seems to be working fine every time and even if it fails somehow that I tested as well, it doesn't keep trying repeatedly and instead stops calling. So, probably there's some specific scenario when that happens that I don't know about. I'll be upgrading my app to use RxJava2 soon anyways, maybe that has something to do with it.